# Как удалить значение из массива (json формат)

Tags: php, json

В куки записал json строку

```
[fav] => ["259","258","261","263","265"]
```

Каким образом на php удалить любое значение?
 Пробовал и `unset($_COOKIE['fav'][258])` и `unset($_COOKIE['fav']['258'])`, ничего не подходит.

Comment: считать куку, распаковать, удалить, запаковать, записать взад

Comment: ['fav' => ["259","258","261","263","265"]] Вот так будет выглядеть запись массива к которму можно обратится через $_COOKIE['fav']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как видно что Ваш массив является ассоциативным массивом. И поэтому удаление значение из ассоциативного массива будет таким образом:

```
$arr = ['fav' => ["259","258","261","263","265"]];

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";

/* Это входной массив со всеми значениями:
Array
(
    [fav] => Array
        (
            [0] => 259
            [1] => 258
            [2] => 261
            [3] => 263
            [4] => 265
        )

)
*/

$del_val = "259";

$sub_arr = "fav";

if (($key = array_search($del_val, $arr[$sub_arr])) !== false) {
    unset($arr[$sub_arr][$key]);
}

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Это вид массива после удаление значение **259** из под массива **fav**

```
Array
(
    [fav] => Array
        (
            [1] => 258
            [2] => 261
            [3] => 263
            [4] => 265
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

В куки вы записали, как вы правильно заметили, **строку**, поэтому все попытки удалить элемент как `$_COOKIE['fav'][...]` обречены на провал.
Вам следует прочитать эту куку, привести ее к виду массива, удалить то что вам не нужно, затем вписать ее обратно.
Если опустить подробности с проверкой ее наличия, то примерно так:

```
$fjson = $_COOKIE['fav'];
$fav = json_decode($fjson);
$remove = 258;
$fav = array_diff($fav, [$remove]);
set_cookie('fav', json_encode($fav));
```

способов удалить значение из массива можно придумать множество:

- найти расхождение как в примере
- найти позицию элемента (`array-search`) и удалить
- сделать `flip` + `unset`
- написать `array_filter`

и так далее.

Comment: Не думаю что стоит учить людей удалять элемент массива array_diff`ом или другими функциями которые выполняют другое действие. Удаление ими элементов в массиве побочное действие основоного сравнения или там фильтрирования. Стоило бы уточнить что ими стоит пользоваться при необходимости удаления нескольких элементов или получения разници, общей части массива. На ошибку в вопросе ответ не отвечает.

Comment: @ErroRErroR ну давайте подождем, может в пхп8 появится функция `array_remove($val)` удаляющая элемент массива по его значению.

Comment: Своей длинной террадой хотел сказать `Буть проще`.

Answer (score 0):

Если упустить мометы с json и так далее, то не удалялось потому что вы пытались удалить по значению, а надо по индексу.

```
unset($_COOKIE['fav'][1])
```

Для удаления элемента со значением "258"

```
unset($_COOKIE['fav'][2])
```

Для удаления элемента со значением "261"

Comment: в упущенных вами моментах и кроется смысл проблем автора. Индекс ему тоже не интересен. он знает только значение. массив очевидно данамический с произвольными элементами и содержит некие id товаров или еще чего, помеченные пользователем как избранные. И задача - добавление/удаление указанного id из массива

Comment: Знает он индекс или нет удалить элемент массива можно только по индексу.  Как этот индекс будет найден другое дело. Человек задавший вопрос должен понять почему его код не работает. В данном конкретном приложенном коде.

Comment: ну дак в данном конкретном коде  не работает, потому что в куках json-строка а не массив.